# Output does not produce using method and struct

Tags: c++, oop, io

I try this code using a method, array, and struct, but it doesn't produce output at all.

I also use most types of include, but it still doesn't produce any output.

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<stream>
#include<string>
#include<stream>
using namespace std;

struct PetLabel {
    string petname;
    string pettype;
    int petprice;
    string petowner;
    string phoneno;    
}; 

PetLabel pet [10]; 
stringstream ss;   

void DataPet();
void petPrice();
void findOwner();

int main(){
    DataPet();
    findOwner();
    petPrice();
    return 0;
}

void DataPet(){
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("petSold.txt"); 
    string cnvt[10]; 
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        getline(infile, pet[i].petname, ',');
        getline(infile, pet[i].pettype, ',');
        getline(infile, cnvt[i], ',');
        ss << cnvt[i];
        ss >> pet[i].petprice; 
        getline(infile, pet[i].petowner, ',');
        getline(infile, pet[i].phoneno);
        ss.clear();
    }
    infile.close(); 
}

void findOwner(){
    int chosen;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        if (pet[i].petname == "Uyasolu"){
            i = chosen;
        }
    }
    cout << "Owner name : " << pet[chosen].petowner << " Phone no : " << pet[chosen].phoneno << endl;
}

void petPrice(){
    ofstream outfile("catSold.txt");
    outfile << "The cat sold with price greater than RM1000" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        if (pet[i].petprice > 1000){
            cout << pet[i].petname << "," << pet[i].pettype << "," << pet[i].petprice << "," << pet[i].petowner << "," << pet[i].phoneno << endl;
        }
    }
    outfile.close();
}
```

the output that I get is:

```
Owner name :  Phone no :
```

but I can't understand, because there is no syntax error at all.

Is there anything I can add, so I can get the right output?

Answer (score 2):

This method is weird:

```
void findOwner(){
    int chosen;
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
        if (pet[i].petname == "Uyasolu"){
            i = chosen;
         }

     }
     cout<<"Owner name : "<<pet[chosen].petowner<<" Phone no :              "<<pet[chosen].phoneno<<endl;
}
```

I think you mean `chosen = i` instead.

Comment: but it still doesnt give the output

Comment: @KhadijahHisham Have you checked what is in your `pet` array? Does it have an owner called `"Uyasolu"`? That should be the first thing that you do.

Answer (score 2):

`findOwner()` is coded wrong.

`int chosen;` is uninitialized before the loop is entered. Inside the loop, `chosen` is never updated (`i` is updated instead, which affects the looping).  After the loop is done, `chosen` has an *indeterminate* value, so accessing `pet[chosen]` is [*undefined behavior*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

It should look more like this instead:

```
void findOwner(){
    int chosen = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        if (pet[i].petname == "Uyasolu"){
            chosen = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (chosen != -1)
        cout << "Owner name : " << pet[chosen].petowner << " Phone no : " << pet[chosen].phoneno << endl;
    else
        cout << "Pet not found" << endl;
}
```

Alternatively:

```
void findOwner(){
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        if (pet[i].petname == "Uyasolu"){
            cout << "Owner name : " << pet[i].petowner << " Phone no : " << pet[i].phoneno << endl;
            return;
        }
    }
    cout << "Pet not found" << endl;
}
```

---

There are some other issues in your code, too:

- don't use `<conio.h>`, its old, and you are not using anything from it anyway.
- you have `#include<stream>` twice, and also `<stream>` should be `<sstream>`
- `string cnvt[10];` should be `string cnvt;` and then `cnvt[i]` should be `cnvt`. You don't need a whole array when you are converting only 1 `string` at a time.
- `ss.clear();` does not do what you think it does.  You need to use `ss.str("")` instead. Or, simply move the declaration of `ss` inside the loop as a local variable so it is destroyed and recreated on each loop iteration.
- `petPrice()` is creating an output `catSold.txt` file, but is not writing anything to it.